# Solving a system of three linear equations with three variables in a different manner.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

Given the system of equations

$$x-y+2z=6$$

$$x-ay-az=0$$

$$-ax+y+7z=b$$

I'm asked to find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the system

$$A\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6\\ 0\\ b \end{pmatrix}$$

is independent, as well as for when $(0,-2,2)$ is the only solution. The natural way forward would be to find the rref of the corresponding matrix, the issue is that I end up getting some complicated rational functions of $a$ and $b$, so I wonder if there is a simpler way of solving the excercise.

I've also thought of computing the determinant and determining when it is $0$. However, the inverse of $A$ also involves some complicated rational functions. Is there a simpler way of tackling the problem?

Comment: The function is not complicated for the inverse. The determinant is $- 3(a + 3)(a - 1)$. Is this a complicated function in $a$??

Comment: It is. https://es.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-inverse-calculator/inversa%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%26-1%262%5C%5C%201%26-a%26-a%5C%5C%20-a%261%267%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D

Comment: If you write the determinant in front, the inverse is easy.

Comment: Ah I see. How would you recommend computing the inverse though? Even if the determinant can be factored at the end it still seems like computing the inverse is a tedious process.

Comment: Maybe Cramer's rule is the fastest way?